# What can I do against someone who downvotes all my posts?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, serial-voting

I downvoted someones answer, he asked why and i gave him the answer. He insulted me with

> go get a life ... douche

(or something like that) deleted his answer and is now downvoting all my posts.

What is the right way to deal with him?

Comment: **REVENGE DOWNVOTE HIM BACK!** `>:D` Just kidding, *don't* do that. Duplicate of flood of downvotes question? Probably.

Comment: And yet some people still wonder why comments are not required for downvotes.

Answer (score 19):

Initially do nothing.

The system should spot this behaviour and automatically reversed the votes.

If by the next day some (or all) of the votes haven't been reversed flag one of your posts for moderator attention and we'll look into to it for you.

Comment: Pretty sure the system is not that smart.

Answer (score 11):

First, you don't engage the user if they act inappropriate.

Second, flag the comments for a moderator to review.

Third, don't engage because it just escalates.

As far as the specific comments, we'd already been notified of the comments and they have been removed.  If the votes are not caught via the script that detects these at night, then flag it for a moderator to review.